# Close vote "Not a coding service"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What is the correct reason to put in for questions that are obviously asking stackoverflow to solve their homework/assignment/chore?

Example: (Link is omitted to avoid meta effect)

> I am in need of some help with this task:
>
> Develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence,
>   stores theses in a list and replaces each word in the original
>   sentence with the position of that word in the list.
>
> Any help appreciated. Thanks
>
> More detail can be provided if needed.

Comment: Depends, but often it's "Too broad"

Comment: Well that is too broad of a question, so "too broad". I suggest never closing a question ONLY on the basis of "this is not a coding service". You usually either have "too broad", or "unclear what you're asking" that is a good reason for these

Comment: "Too localized" would be the best choice but it isn't around anymore.  You now have to pick the exact opposite: "Too broad".  Could be reasoned out, you have no idea how to properly answer this question because you don't know what the OP is stuck on.  So you'd have to cover every possible angle.

Comment: You can just write a custom closure reason.

Comment: Thank you @approxiblue I couldn't find that.

Comment: So what's the outcome of the discussion? There everyone seemed really supportive of the reason. Why don't we have it now?

Comment: Because if every close reason we all agree on would be added we would have 42 close reasons and counting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the reason too broad as there are many ways that could be approached to deal with the problem which would result in many answers with the same results but vastly different approaches.